# SpringBoot: Download Multipart file with individually set MimeType

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to download a file with Spring Boot:

```
@GetMapping("/downloadById.{id}/{fileName}")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Object> downloadById(@PathVariable("id") int id, HttpServletResponse response) {
    final MultipartFile file = fileUtils.getMultiPartFileById(id, fileName, mimeType);
    response.setContentType(mimeType);
    response.setContentLength(file.getBytes().length);
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
    FileCopyUtils.copy(file.getBytes(), response.getOutputStream());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response.toString(), HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
}
```

With this approach I get all the time an exception:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class java.lang.String] with preset Content-Type 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text'
```

whereas the Content-Type is the one I've set.

Setting the MimeType  into the `@GetMapping` is out of scope because I multiple different file types. Therefore I set it directly in the `contentType`. Which works more or less (except the exception :-/)

Q: How to tell SpringBoot to **NOT** use a `String` converter and just process the response with the set MimeType?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption from @Puce was correct, i.e. the conversion into a `String` is wrong. Basically I need to return `StreamingResponseBody`. The whole code looks like

```
@GetMapping("/downloadById.{id}/{fileName}")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> downloadById(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
    final MultipartFile file = fileUtils.getMultiPartFileById(id, fileName, mimeType);

    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(mimeType));
    headers.setContentLength(file.getBytes().length);
    headers.setContentDisposition(ContentDisposition.builder("inline").filename(fileName).build());
    final StreamingResponseBody ret = out -> {
        out.write(file.getBytes());
    };

    return new ResponseEntity<>(ret, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The main advantage with this approach is that I can return as well regular `String` in case of an exception.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but `response.toString()` in `return new ResponseEntity<>(response.toString(), HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);` might cause the issue.

Try something like:

```
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> downloadById(...){
    ...
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
                    "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getFilename() + "\"")
            .contentType(mimeType)
            .body(file.getBytes());
}
```

Comment: When I try your approach - which looks very promising I get `No converter for [class [B] with preset Content-Type 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text'` :-(

Comment: @LeO Did you return ResponseEntity<byte[]> ?

Comment: Almost exactly the way you suggested. The `contentType` needs to be set differently - but this seems OK since the error message shows me the set type.

Comment: I guess that Spring Boot tries to be smart and sends any string as defined and not according to the set content type. And this especially for GET requests. For POST and PATCH it seems that a different behavior is used. Is there a way to tell Spring not to convert the return value?